# How can i convert string to datetime SQL

Tags: sql, datetime, converters

I have **"2016-02-09 14:59:31 UTC"** on my SQL SELECT. I want to change it to **14:59** format. How can i convert or parse it?

**"2016-02-09 14:59:31 UTC"** in string format. 
**14:59** must be in `datetime` format. It could be **"2016-02-09 14:59"** like that. I can do it after that.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Try this in SQL Server:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(16), '2016-02-09 14:59:31 UTC', 121)
```

In MYSQL

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT('2016-02-09 14:59:31 UTC', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),RIGHT('2016-02-09 14:59:31 UTC',12),108)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your using `MySQL` use the `STR_TO_DATE` function.

```
SELECT (STR_TO_DATE('2016-02-09 14:59:31 UTC', '%c/%e/%Y %r'))
FROM yourtable
```

Answer (score 0):

*How can i convert string to datetime SQL:*

in SQL Server you can use CAST:

```
SELECT  CAST(LEFT('2016-02-09 14:59:31 UTC', 19) AS DATETIME)
```

Result is:

```
2016-09-02 14:59:31.000
```